# css media not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, media

в css медия не работает смотру через инспект медия  понимает но параметр нет

```css
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .sub1 {
    height: 298px;
  }
}

.sub1 {
  transition: 1s;
  height: 366px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="subl">
  <img class="sub1" src="img/sub1a.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="k-d">Top Brands at discount prices<br>ELECTRONISC<br>SALE<br>Smartphone & Cell phone<br>
    <button class="lol">GET IT NOW</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что среди равных селекторов побеждает последний. Поменяй местами @media и обычные.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, а здесь работает. Может, у вас порядок подключения `css` файлов не правильный.

```css
.sub1 {
  transition: 1s;
  height: 366px;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .sub1 {
    height: 298px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="subl">
  <img class="sub1" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="">
  <div class="k-d">Top Brands at discount prices<br>ELECTRONISC<br>SALE<br>Smartphone & Cell phone<br>
    <button class="lol">GET IT NOW</button>
  </div>
</div>
```